# Do boosting algorithms use only the latest model, or all past models to form the bootstrap sample?

Tags: boosting

In [this Udacity explanation of boosting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GM3CDQfQ4sw), we use the output of all previous iteration's models  to form the predictions of current iteration. (eg: majority voting  for a binary classifier) Then, we measure the error of our current iteration, and bootstrap sample from the training set.

My question is: Can we take ONLY the output of the previous iteration, measure the error, then resample? Or is that not considered boosting?

Which approach is more commonly used in practice?

Comment: This will depend on implementation, but I think your idea is more common, that is take in consideration the errors of the previous iteration.

Comment: Just to be clear, that is a description of AdaBoost.